# How to show JavaScript error stack trace for source map instead of minified code?

Tags: javascript, webpack, google-chrome-devtools, create-react-app

I have a `create-react-app` web app deployed to production with source map enabled and logging errors to the console. I would like to debug the error shown below, but it is giving me a stack trace for the minified JS file.

How can I get the stack trace mapped to my original code? It seems to do that partially already because hovering over `xhr.js:30` in the top right links to some `node_modules` code from `axios`, but the rest links to the minified file.

This error only happens in production and I can't debug without knowing what line in my code is causing it.

[image]